# Right side bar is not being displayed properly in magento

Tags: php, css, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.8.1 and i am just enable the right side column on product view page.

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

but it is display in footer not in right side of main container.

Website link: [site](http://52.74.231.134/index.php/)

[image]

please tell me why it is happen and how to fix this

Comment: I don't see your right side bar as in the picture on your page?

Comment: This banner and pay pal logo is in right side bar only, but it show in footer

Comment: It's not in the footer. It's nowhere to be seen ...

Comment: right side bar is enable only for product view page. you check on this link: http://52.74.231.134/index.php/bath-skin-and-health-care/bath-and-skin-care/soaps-shampoos-and-body-wash/chicco-no-tears-soap-0m-75g.html

Comment: problems with html cutting. in default magento theme http://prntscr.com/7z8dsd there must be a wrapper[class=main] around left and right columns, while in your cutting class "main" is on the left column, left column should be lesser in width to let the right col rise up to the same level, plus it must float:left